# LDAP GDM Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04, openldap

I have Open LDAP server running on Ubuntu Server 10.04 with OSX, Windows and Ubuntu 10.04 Desktops as clients.

GDM login fails from Ubuntu 10.04 with User Name length(UID length) greater than 9. The same machine can login through ssh. When I tried the same users from Windows and OSX that worked.

The issue is with Ubuntu 10.04 GDM login. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: I have OpenLDAP on lucid64 and lucid x86 desktops authenticate against it without the problem you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed this issue.

I had to create Home directory for the Users with user name length greater than 9. Then changed ownership.

## mkdir /home/ubuntutestuser

## chown -R 1017:10000  /home/ubuntutestuser

- I got uid and gid from #getent passwd | grep ubuntutestuser

Then rebooted the server and successfully logged in via GDM or Gnome-Desktop

Comment: You should add pam_mkhomedir.so to your PAM configuration.

Comment: I have that already and home directories are successfully created for other users

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like PAM might be rejecting your input, I'm no pam expert though.

I have two suggestions.

First, to rule GDM out as an issue you can attempt to log into a regular console. Press the contrl+alt+f3 keys (Almost any f-key really will work) and you should be at a black screen prompt. Try and log in this way. Just press the alt+right/left arrow keys together a few times and you'll eventually be back at the GDM screen. (Usually it's ctrl+alt+f7)

Second suggestion, on the machine you are attempting to log into I recommend you watch /var/log/auth.log (as a user who can log in) and see what the output is when you try to log in using gdm.

```
tail -f /var/log/auth.log
```

Then make your GDM log in attempt with a long user name.

We should learn something after all this.

If you have admin access to the OpenLDAP server you can change the log level to a very verbost level and then follow the logs there too to see exactly what user name is attempting to authenticate when the failure happens.

Answer (score 0):

Please have look at the /var/log/auth.log. Strage that the successful login too has the same errors. But I was able to login to ssh. Please let me know your comments. Possibly a bug with 10.04. This worked fine on CentOS. I planning to try this out on 10.10

**Errored login**

gdm-session-worker[1482]: pam_succeed_if(gdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "ubuntutester"
gdm-session-worker[1482]: pam_unix(gdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=  user=ubuntutester
gdm-session-worker[1482]: pam_unix(gdm:session): session opened for user ubuntutester by (uid=0)
gnome-keyring-daemon[1488]: couldn't connect to dbus session bus: /bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: No protocol specified#012Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
gnome-keyring-daemon[1488]: gkd_dbus_secrets_startup: assertion `dbus_conn' failed
gnome-keyring-daemon[1488]: gkd_dbus_secrets_startup: assertion`dbus_conn' failed
gnome-keyring-daemon[1488]: The SSH agent was already initialized
polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for session /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2 (system bus name :1.35 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_IN)

**Successful login**

gdm-session-worker[1810]: pam_succeed_if(gdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "testuser"
gdm-session-worker[1810]: pam_unix(gdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=  user=testuser
gdm-session-worker[1827]: pam_succeed_if(gdm:auth): requirement "user ingroup nopasswdlogin" not met by user "testuser"
gdm-session-worker[1827]: pam_unix(gdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=  user=testuser
gdm-session-worker[1827]: pam_unix(gdm:session): session opened for user testuser by (uid=0)
gnome-keyring-daemon[1833]: couldn't connect to dbus session bus: /bin/dbus-launch terminated abnormally with the following error: No protocol specified#012Autolaunch error: X11 initialization failed.
gnome-keyring-daemon[1833]: gkd_dbus_secrets_startup: assertion `dbus_conn' failed
gnome-keyring-daemon[1833]: gkd_dbus_secrets_startup: assertion`dbus_conn' failed
gnome-keyring-daemon[1833]: The SSH agent was already initialized
polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for session /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session4 (system bus name :1.64 [/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1], object path /org/gnome/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale en_IN)

Thanks